# Run a specific python version in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

This might be just a syntax error in Windows Powershell, but I'm not able to run a python script with a specific python version (I have two installations).

I have a batch file in which the following command works:

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe" myscript.py
```

But if I open a PowerShell in the folder containing the python script, I get an error:

```
At line:1 char:45
+ ... C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe" myscript.py
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'myscript.py' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I tried also without double-quotes, with single-quotes, and by specifying the path also to the python script:

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe" C:\mydata\myscript.py
```

With quotes on both parts:

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe" "C:\mydata\myscript.py"
```

But with a similar error.

What is the correct way to write this command?

Comment: The reason I believe this is happening inside the `bin\python.exe` when you run `python.exe myscript.py` is because `myscript.py` doesn't exist in `bin/` of QGIS. Instead go to `mydata/` directory and then run `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe myscript.py` which will use the `python.exe` path provided and then run `myscript.py` present in the `mydata` directory.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately however, as specified in the question, I am already in `C:\mydata` which is where I launch the PowerShell. It is because that didn't work that I included the path to the `.py` file in the first place.

Comment: If you have `python` on your path, what do you get when you run `where python` on your `cmd`?

Comment: In `cmd`, that returns the paths for both of my installs: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe`
`C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe`

Comment: What happens when you run `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe" myscript.py` from `cmd` instead of `ps`?

Comment: I got `ImportError: No module named site` It seems the QGIS python executable isn't loading properly, even if it does work fine when launched from a batch file.. Probably has to do with specifying environment paths, which was what I was trying to avoid. Unless you see other explanations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158338/discussion-between-sudheesh-singanamalla-and-sc28).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`&` *Call operator* or `.` *Dot sourcing operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) as follows (choose one):

- `. "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe" "C:\mydata\myscript.py"`
- `& "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe" "C:\mydata\myscript.py"`
- `. "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe" "myscript.py"`
- `& "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe" "myscript.py"`

**Explanation**:

In Powershell, `"a string"` at start of a line means the same as `Write-Output "a string"`  (see *Example 1* in [`Write-Output` cmdlet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output)). Hence, in the first example `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe" myscript.py`

- `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe"` = the 1st token of type *string*

  - => the powershell interpreter expects that the whole line represents a positional argument of the `Write-Output` at position `0` i.e. an array of PS objects (`PSObject[]`), and
- `myscript.py` = an unexpected token.

Comment: Many thanks, this is technically the correct answer: the command now works. Unfortunately, I still cannot run the script due to `ImportError: No module named site`. This might be unrelated to the actual question, and more related to how the QGIS Python version is organized, but if you have any idea how to resolve this that'd be great!

Comment: @sc28 You could ask another question about `site` module or [edit your current question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47140927/edit). Share all `import …` and `from XXX import …` statements from currently called `myscript.py`. FYI, in can get from my  _standard_ python versions: `<module 'site' from 'C:\Python\Python27\lib\site.pyc'>` and `<module 'site' from 'C:\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\site.py'>`. (Please add full traceback for _ImportError: No module named site_).

Comment: @sc28 Please  ask another question about `site` module using tags `python`, `QGIS`. Please avoid extending scope/topic of current question.